# YAJL installation and build with xcode 3.2.2

Tags: iphone, json

i've tried following the guide at http://github.com/gabriel/yajl-objc in order to install YAJL into my project but when I try to add a line for the examples i'm getting build errors.

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libYAJLIPhone.a(YAJLDocument.o)


  objc-class-ref-to-NSString in libYAJLIPhone.a(YAJLParser.o)
```

Basically i'm getting 18 build errors.

have i missed an .o file or something?

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong sdk version of yajl.